# Microsoft.XMLHTTP request works in Excel VBA but not in Visual Studio Code

Tags: vba, visual-studio-code, vbscript, msxml2.xmlhttp

The following code works fine in an Excel VBA module

```
Sub test()

    Dim restReq, url, apiKey
    url = "https://some.server.com/?param1=123"
    apiKey = "123342545"
    Set restReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    
    restReq.Open "GET", url, False
    restReq.SetRequestHeader "accept", "application/json"
    restReq.SetRequestHeader "X-ApiKey", apiKey
    restReq.send ("")
    
    'MsgBox restReq.getAllResponseHeaders
    MsgBox restReq.responseText

End Sub
```

But when I run the exactly same code from Visual Studio Code, I get this non helpful error message:

> MSXML3.DLL A security problem occurred.

Any ideas, where the difference could be?

Comment: Try using `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")` instead.

Comment: This results in: MSXML6.DLL A security problem occurred.

Comment: Sounds like a context and cert store issue.  Meaning: Excel might be capable of accessing the Windows certificate store in your user context, but VS Code may not.  See if switching to use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` and ignoring all cert errors by adding `restReq.setOption 2, 13056` helps any.

Comment: With this change it says: Certificate needed for client authorization. Shouldn't exactly this be avoided by option2?